# Extract mutations from fasta sequences

Tags: bioinformatics, sequence-analysis

I have a large amount of protein sequences in the .fasta format and I would like to extract only the amino acid mutations from these sequences, so that, in the end, I want to have a list that looks something like this:
I456L, W675T, etc
Is there a program or way to do this?
Thankful

Comment: Are all of your sequences of the same protein, are they all the same length, do you know which one is the WT / baseline?

Comment: Yes, the proteins are of the same, in the same length and I have a reference genome to compare

Comment: I'd blastp, and parse the alignment you get back.

Comment: I would suggest posting this question on https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions.